# Problems erasing and adding elements to std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm having some troubles adding and removing elements from an std::vector (`population`, in the example code). What I want to do is to erase an element if a condition is satisfied and copy the element if instead other conditions are satisfied. Here's the code:

```
    for( int i = 0; i < walkers_num;  i++) {

        if( population[i].molteplicity == 0 ) { 
            population[i] = population.back();
            population.pop_back();
            i--;

        } else {

            for( int j = population[i].molteplicity; j > 1; j-- ) { 
                population.push_back(population[i]); 
            }
        }
    }
    walkers_num = population.size();
```

What I get is:

> *** error for object 0x7f86a1404498: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

I guess I'm using some std::vector property in a wrong way, since a very similar algorithm (conceptually they seem identical to me) seems to work if population is instead an std::list:

```
list<Walker>::iterator it;
list<Walker>::iterator end = thread_population[i].end();

for ( it = thread_population[i].begin(); it != end; ) {
if( it->molteplicity == 0 ) { 
        it = thread_population[i].erase(it); 
        continue;
    }

    for( int j = it->molteplicity; j > 1; j-- ) { 
        population.push_back(*it); 
    }

    ++it;
}
walkers_num = population.size();
```

Can you help me?

Comment: How can the same algorithm work for std::list even though it doesn't have an `operator[]`?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit sloppy.. I'm editing the post right now.

Comment: `population[i] = population.back();
 population.pop_back();` seems problematic. However the first line should not compile.

Comment: Your code changes the number of elements in `population` but I don't see `walkers_num` ever get adjusted.  It seems possible (depending on the data in the vector) that you start accessing elements past the end of the vector.

Comment: What is walkers_num? How do you guarantee, that i is a valid ibdex? Please provide a MCVE (or at least some sample in and output and the definition of population)

Comment: @MichaelBurr you're right, I forgot to put that part in the sample. Now it is complete.

Comment: @SimoneBolognini: unfortunately, that doesn't update `walkers_num` until after the loop is finished, and the damage is done. it might be nice to provide a small, complete, compilable example that repros the problem (so have it also populate the vector) like MikeMB suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted quite enough code.

I'm assuming you omitted at the start of the fragment:

```
walkers_num = population.size();
```

And are trying to visit the whole array. In that case try:

```
walkers_num = population.size();
for( int i = 0; i < walkers_num;  i++) {
        if( population[i].molteplicity == 0 ) { 
            population[i] = population.back();
            population.pop_back();
            i--; 
            --walkers_num; //Array has been shortened.
        }
    //....
```

You seem to have realised the length has changed because you put `walkers_num = population.size();` at the end. You need to keep track throughout.

There are subtle reasons why your iterator code is likely to work but technically just as invalid. You're not allowed to assume `end` is valid after a modification.

Comment: Hopefully this is my problem, as reasonably it seems to be. Thank you very much! I'm trying it right now.